# How to cast a bit sequence of arbitrary length to a signed or unsigned integer in Python?

Tags: python, integer, bit, unsigned, signed

I need to cast bit sequences of arbitrary length to signed or unsigned integers. Those sequences are represented as strings. for example, I have to cast `'001100100110100101110011001010'` to an unsigned integer and `'10000000'` to a signed integer.

I used `int('10000000', 2)`, but I haven't been able to find an intuitive approach to switch between signed/unsigned. Is there a straight-forward way to do this in Python?

Comment: What non-intuitive approach have you found?

Comment: @martineau maybe intuitive was not the correct word here, but I've used the library bitstring. Isn't there a way to simply do this in Python?

Comment: How are you planning to recognize signed number without strict size of variable in bytes? `0b10000000` is `-128` if it's one byte variable and `128` it it's 2+ bytes. First bit in integer value defines sign (`0` - postive, `1` - negative).

Comment: `int('-10000000', 2)` will give you `-128` decimal—so adding a leading `-` character appears to be one way of doing it for arbitrary length sequences.